# Axios.post works, but jQuery.ajax gives Cross Origin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Solved:

Turns out `content-type: false` was the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/1694116

---

Question, for posterity:

For quick prototyping purposes I used Axios to `POST` to an API, and everything was fine and dandy. Due to client requirements, I cannot use Axios in deployment, I have to use jQuery. This is where the problem lies.

With Axios, the server sends the correct headers as a response:
[image]

Request header:
[image]

However, with jQuery, I do not get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header: 
[image]

Request header:
[image]

The payload is **exactly** the same, as I am making the requests at the same time (for testing).

Naturally, because the jQuery response is missing the correct header response, I get the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.

Code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var input = this.$form.find('#image');

formData.append('image', input[0].files);
formData.append('action', 'upload_image');
formData.append('api_key', this.apiKey);

function successCb(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

// This is all that was required to get Axios to work
axios.post(apiEndpoint, formData)
    .then(successCb);

// jQuery Ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: apiEndpoint,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: formData,
    success: successCb,
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
});
```

Things to note:

If I don't set the `contentType` in jQuery, the request does a pre-flight request, which fails. Am I missing something with jQuery here?

If I set the `dataType` in jQuery to `'json'`, I still get the error. If I set the `dataType` to `'jsonp'`, the request doesn't even get made.

Using `XMLHttpRequest()` works.

Comment: I'd look at the *request* headers to see what's different, then look for the jQuery option to make it emit/not emit whatever's missing/added/different.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added screenshots of the request headers. The only difference is the `Accept` header. Explicitly forcing the `Accept` header does not make a difference.

Comment: Turns out `content-type: false` was the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/1694116

Comment: Odd that that and what it links to both say that jQuery will set the content type wrong if you don't do that, but it looks right in the request headers you posted. Still, good find!